# PDF gerado com iTextSharp adicionando imagem fica qualidade ruim

Tags: c#, imagem, pdf, itextsharp

Tenho um arquivo de imagem que preciso passar para PDF e para isso estou utilizando o **iTextSharp**.

Para tal estou tentando da seguinte maneira:

```cs
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var stream = new FileStream("document.pdf", FileMode.Create))
    {
        using (var document = new Document(PageSize.A4))
        {
            PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, stream);

            document.SetMargins(20, 20, 20, 20);
            document.AddCreationDate();
            document.Open();

            using (var picture = new Bitmap("model256.bmp"))
            {
                double percentage;
                if (picture.Height > picture.Width)
                    percentage = document.PageSize.Height / picture.Height;
                else
                    percentage = document.PageSize.Width / picture.Width;

                using (var newPicture = Util.ResizeImage(picture, 
                    Convert.ToInt32(picture.Width * percentage), 
                    Convert.ToInt32(picture.Height * percentage)))
                {
                    var image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(newPicture, 
                        BaseColor.WHITE);
                    image.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;

                    document.Add(image);
                    document.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Com esta ajuda para redimensionar:

```cs
public static class Util
{
    public static Bitmap ResizeImage(Bitmap bitmap, int newWidth, int newHeight)
    {
        var width = bitmap.Width;
        var heigth = bitmap.Height;

        if (width > newWidth || heigth > newHeight)
        {
            if (width > heigth)
            {
                heigth = (heigth * newWidth) / width;
                width = 500;
            }
            else
            {
                width = (width * newHeight) / heigth;
                heigth = 500;
            }
        }

        var image = bitmap.GetThumbnailImage(width, heigth, null, new System.IntPtr(0));
        return new Bitmap(image);
    }
}
```

O formato das imagens é **bmp**.

Aqui tem as imagens colocadas lado a lado para comparação

**O editor do stackoverflow redimensiona as imagens e por isso aqui ela aparenta estar ruim. Mas ao clicar em ambas as imagens ela aparecem em tamanho real e com a qualidade correta.**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como gerar o PDF com boa qualidade de image?

### EDIÇÃO

---

#### Fazendo uso de Graphics

Usando Graphics para tentar melhorar a imagem de saída também não teve melhorias.

```cs
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var stream = new FileStream("document.pdf", FileMode.Create))
    {
        using (var document = new Document(PageSize.A4))
        {
            PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, stream);

            document.SetMargins(20, 20, 20, 20);
            document.AddCreationDate();
            document.Open();

            using (var picture = new Bitmap("original.bmp"))
            {
                var width = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(
                    document.PageSize.Width - 40));
                var height = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(
                    ((float)picture.Height / (float)picture.Width) * (width)));

                using (var newPicture = Util.RedimensionarImagem(
                    picture, width, height, PixelFormat.Format48bppRgb))
                {
                    var image = Image.GetInstance(newPicture, BaseColor.WHITE);
                    image.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;

                    document.Add(image);
                    document.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

E a rotina de redimensionamento:

```cs
public static Image RedimensionarImagem(Image image, int width, int height, PixelFormat pf)
{
    if (image != null)
    {
        var newImage = new Bitmap(width, height, pf);
        using (var gr = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
        {
            //gr.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
            gr.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            //gr.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
            gr.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height);
            gr.Dispose();
            return newImage;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Imagem de exemplo:

[image: PDF com imagem convertida gerada com graphics]

#### Redimensionando pelo objeto **iTextSharp.text.Image**

Ao usar a imagem original, sem redimensioná-la, e redimensionando o objeto *Image* de *iTextSharp* consegui ter uma pequena melhora.

Em várias tentativas de redimensionamento da imagem buscando a melhor conversão eu verifiquei que ainda assim havia perda ao passar a imagem para o *Image* do *iTextSharp* e então para o *Document*

Mas ainda assim apresenta uma imagem com baixa qualidade!

Código:

```cs
using (var document = new Document(PageSize.A4))
{
    document.SetMargins(20, 20, 20, 20);
    document.AddCreationDate();
    document.Open();

    using (var picture = new Bitmap("original.bmp"))
    {
        var width = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(document.PageSize.Width - 40));
        var height = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(((float)picture.Height / (float)picture.Width) * (width)));

        using (var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, stream))
        {
            writer.SetPdfVersion(PdfWriter.PDF_VERSION_1_7);
            writer.CompressionLevel = PdfStream.NO_COMPRESSION;

            document.Open();

            var image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(bitmap, BaseColor.WHITE);
            image.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;

            image.SetDpi(600, 600);
            image.ScaleToFit(width, heigth);

            document.Add(image);
            document.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Resultado

[image: com Image do iTextSharp]

Answer (score 1):

No seu método de redimensionar imagem, você está utilizando

```
var image = bitmap.GetThumbnailImage(width, heigth, null, new System.IntPtr(0));
return new Bitmap(image);
```

Esse método retorna uma miniatura da imagem passada. Você não deve utilizar isso.

Segue uma função que utilizo para redimensionar imagem:

```
public static System.Drawing.Image RedimensionarImagem(System.Drawing.Image srcImage, int newWidth, int newHeight, PixelFormat pf)
{
    if (srcImage != null)
    {
        Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight, pf);
        using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage((Image)newImage))
        {
            //gr.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
            gr.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            //gr.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
            gr.DrawImage(srcImage, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);// new Rectangle(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight));
            gr.Dispose();
            return (Image)newImage;
        }
    }
    else
        return null;

}
```

Para executar a chamada:

```
var image = RedimensionarImagem(bitmap, width, height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
```

Documentação do método GetThumbnailImage: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.drawing.image.getthumbnailimage(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta! Até consegui uma imagem redimensionada com mais qualidade. Entretanto ainda obtenho má qualidade quando passo para o PDF.  Consegui uma pequena melhoria ao redimensionar a imagem original dentro de *Image* do *iTextSharp*.